# TFS 2015.4 TF400927 Error while upgrading and now completely

Tags: tfs

My TFS upgrade from 2013 to 2015.4 is being blocked by this issue

> TF400927: The following team project collection is in detached state: MyDAS. Sql Server hosting the database: SRC2TFS01\SqlExpress. Database name: Tfs_MyDAS.

I'm not able to bypass this. TFS is now already upgraded. I only have a backup of all the databases (12). I don't have the server image backup. I have to proceed with this upgrade somehow. I tried attaching/detaching the said collection through the console but since setup is not complete, I cannot do that either.

**Attaching:**

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools>TFSConfig Collection /attach /collectiondb:"SRC2TFS01\SQLEXPRESS;Tfs_MyDAS" /collectionName:MyDAS
Logging sent to file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configuration\Logs\CFG_TPC_AT_0629_103101.log
Microsoft (R) TfsConfig - Team Foundation Server Configuration Tool
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Command: collection
Microsoft (R) TfsConfig - Team Foundation Server Configuration Tool
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This command can only be used when the Application Tier feature is configured.
```

**And Detaching:**

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools>TFSConfig Collection /detach /collectionName:MyDAS
Logging sent to file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configuration\Logs\CFG_TPC_AT_0629_103536.log
Microsoft (R) TfsConfig - Team Foundation Server Configuration Tool 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Command: collection 
Microsoft (R) TfsConfig - Team Foundation Server Configuration Tool         
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This command can only be used when the Application Tier feature is configured.
```

I cannot just revert at this stage. I need to know what my options are right now. Launching the new Admin Console is not helping as Application Tier is not configured and none of the Wizards there a working and only require me to launch the Upgrade Wizard.

Please help!

Comment: Existing database claims to be at version Dev12.M62 which is TFS 2013.2 and that ISO/web downloader cannot be found anymore. I cannot reinstall the same version and I cannot install a later service release for 2013 either. I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing is that one of the collections was not correct. I had to uninstall as I couldn't let TFS be down for too long. I reinstalled 2013.2 version which correctly loaded the databases and app tiers. After that, I tried to troubleshoot the collection in question but I noticed that under the status tab in the admin console was showing "Deleting" indefinitely. I tried detach->atttach but it wouldn't work so I detached it and then upgraded to 2015.4. Now TFS is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

First try to **Repair** TFS, (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features), if it doesn't work, you have to uninstall then reinstall the TFS.

Fortunately you have a backup of all the databases.

You can directly install the TFS 2015.4, during the installation you can select using the existing database, or create a new instance then restore the backed up databases (Suggest you create a new instance in case any other issue for the existing databases).

**Summary steps should be:**

1. Uninstall existing TFS
2. Reinstall TFS 2015.4
3. Move the collection database
4. Restore databases
5. Attach the collection
6. Configure the moved team project collection
7. Configure projects

Please see [Move a team project collection](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-project-collection) for details.

You can also reference this similar thread : 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8c69709c-1a78-4e80-8ad0-cacee33a5f45/tfs-2013-update-2-upgrade-problems-with-detached-collection?forum=tfsadmin

Comment: Thing is that one of the collections was not correct. I had to uninstall as I couldn't let TFS be down for too long. I reinstalled 2013.2.